# Not able to Install R package "Rgraphviz" on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: r, osx-lion, graphviz, macports

I have spent a lot of time trying to solve this, but still no luck. I am trying to get Rgraphviz to work with R 2.14.1 on a Max OS X Lion

These are the steps I took in order to install and use Rgraphviz on Mac OS X Lion:

1. Installed graphviz via: `sudo port install graphviz`
2. Checked that the installation was successful : `pkg-config --modversion libgvc`

Result: `2.28.0` <- That means its OK

**Under R 2.14.1**

`source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
    biocLite("Rgraphviz")`

Whenever I try to use the library I get the following error

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rgraphviz', details:
call: value[[3L]](cond)
error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.14/Resources/library/Rgraphviz/libs/i386/Rgraphviz.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.14/Resources/library/Rgraphviz/libs/i386/Rgraphviz.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgvc.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.14/Resources/library/Rgraphviz/libs/i386/Rgraphviz.so

Check that (1) graphviz is installed on your system; (2) the installed version of
graphviz matches '2.26.3'; this is the version used to build this Rgraphviz
package; (3) graphviz is accessible to R, e.g., the path to the graphviz 'bin'
directory is in the system 'PATH' variable.  See additional instructions in the
'README' file of the Rgraphviz 'source' distribution, available at
```

Some things I notice

- The graphviz suggested in the "help" file is 2.26.3 and the graphviz installed by Mac Ports is 2.28.0, but as it is a newer version I don't think this makes a difference, and besides I can not find v 2.26.3
- Suggestion number (3) seems to be the key, but I can't find/don't have a bin directory under graphbiz

Also when I run a `locate Rgraphviz.so` there are no results.

Any clue towards a solution will be much appreciated, 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: To check if it is in your PATH, you can type `dot -V` (`dot` this is one of the executables installed with graphviz): it should return something like `dot - graphviz version 2.26.3 (20100126.1600)`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. It looks like Graphviz is working, I get `dot - graphviz version 2.28.0 (20120119.1845)` so the error is within R. I also tried running R under 64 bits mode, but no luck, same error.

Comment: Not likely to be definitive, but try biocLite("Rgraphiz", type="source") so that the package is built from source and hence installed against the version of graphviz on your machine, rather than installed as a binary file built against the version (2.26.3) on the Bioconductor build machine (the discrepancy suggested by point 2). This might require additional compilation tools on your Mac, but I'm out of my MacOS depth here.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you suggested, and it did not work, but, you gave me an idea, I think you are right regarding building from source and installing against current graphviz version. What I did then was to download and install the package from source from my local machine and now I am getting a different more logical error: "configure: error: /usr/local/bin/dot not found.  Check graphviz installation.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rgraphviz’"
Is there any way I can find were dot is located? Thans again

Comment: Got It! After hours this simple line did the trick "sudo R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-graphviz=/usr/' Rgraphviz_1.32.0.tar.gz" Warning: For some reason it is only working for the 64bits R version...don't know why, but I am fine with that for now. Thanks everyone for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the final answer, the installation seems to work for me! (I still have to check that the package runs properly). Just a quick observation: Graphviz was installed in /usr/local on my machine so that the above command had to be entered as follows:

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-graphviz=/usr/local' Rgraphviz_1.32.0.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

One more fail point. If you used Fink to install graphviz, you may still, like me, encounter separate build errors even after you use the configure arguments to point to graphviz, which now look like:

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-graphviz=/sw' Rgraphviz_1.34.0.tar.gz
```

The installation will fail during build errors for LL_funcs.c because it is looking for libraries that do not install unless you ALSO install graphviz-dev. You will see this:

```
In file included from LL_funcs.c:1:
common.h:31:17: error: gvc.h: No such file or directory
common.h:32:22: error: gvplugin.h: No such file or directory
common.h:35:20: error: gvcext.h: No such file or directory
common.h:39:20: error: gvcjob.h: No such file or directory
```

followed by many more build errors of course. Just be sure to

```
fink install graphviz-dev
```